# How do I click on "Next" button until it disappears in playwright (python)

Tags: python, loops, playwright

Here is the code I am using to click next button the problem is after the first page is loded it closes the browser rather than clicking on the next button until it disappears. (I know it is html website but I am learning Playwright so starting light.)

I am using get_by_text() function, I have used this loop to achieve similar results but with selenium python.

Any suggestion how to make this happen?

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("https://books.toscrape.com/")

while True:
try: 
        next = page.get_by_text("Next")     ## next clicker
        next.click()
except:
    break
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? If so, this isn't correct as-is. Everything should be inside the `with` so the browser and page are valid. When `with` ends, the browser closes.

Comment: Actually, the current indentation doesn't compile.

Comment: Everything is inside With there is mistake from my side I will fix it sorry.

Comment: I uninstall playwright and re-install it and it somehow fixed it idk how but it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you put a break in each loop:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://books.toscrape.com/")

    while True:
        try: 
            next = page.get_by_text("Next")  # next clicker
            next.click()
            sleep(2)
        except Exception:
            break
```